# Select from database where multiple columns in list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a problem with making a selection from my database and checking if multiple columns in row are equal to list of objects. I'm u linq and EF.
I have a list of objects like this:

```
public class Offer
{
    public string OrderID { get; set; }
    public string OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public string Domain { get; set; }
}
```

And this is how I'm trying to select from database

```
return oDB.Offers.Where(w => w.Status == WOStatus.Offer
       //pOffers is a object of type List<Offer>
       && pOffers.Any(o => o.OrderID == w.OrderID &&
       o.OrderNumber == w.OrderNumber && o.Domain == w.Domain)). 
       Select(w => new OffModels.Model { ID = w.ID, OrderID = w.OrderID,
       OrderNumber = w.OrderNumber, 
       Description = w.Description, Visible = w.Visible,
       Domain = w.Domain }).ToList();
```

When I try like this I got error

> "Unable to process the type 'Offer[]', because it has no known mapping to the value layer." (System.NotSupportedException) A System.NotSupportedException was caught: "Unable to process the type 'Offer[]', because it has no known mapping to the value layer."

If I'm not wrong, it's because it can't be translate into SQL query. And one more thing, in this table *Offers* i have almost 5 million records. How to make it to work quickly?

Comment: "And one more thing, in this table Offers i have almost 5 million records. How to make it to work quickly?" - that isn't unusually big in database terms; the short answer is "indexing", but the more complicated answer is "indexing that matches your key queries" - which is frankly why it is IMO usually better to write TSQL in "real" systems.

Comment: I have index on this 3 fiels (OrderID, OrderNumber and Domain), but still I don't know how to select this. How to do it in TSQL when I have a list with 3 fields to compare?

Comment: what you are trying to do require a `join`. A `join` needs two tables. You have to materialize in the db your pOffers object. This materialization may be a subquery/view.

Comment: A composite index is only useful left-to-right, so it will help with OrderId matches, and "OrderId and OrderNumber" matches and "OrderId and OrderNumber and Domain" matches, but not with OrderNumber matches or Domain matches;  I think you need 3 indexes instead

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly but in this I'm trying to select from my database rows which I have from other database and they may have been changed (other columns) and this 3 fields are key in this other database and all 3 have to match the same fields in my db.